# How to transform tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I have to create a function who gives me the differents operations that I have to do with 6 numbers to have the final number.

Here an example :

```
Final number: 50

my 6 number : 
2,5,6,8,8,4,5


my result :   8*6+2=50  or 5*6+8+8+4= 50
.....
```

For the moment I did only the condition:

```
from random import *

# etat = nombre obtenu

randint(0, 20)

nombre1 = randint(0, 200)
nombre2 = randint(0, 200)
nombre3 = randint(0, 200)
nombre4 = randint(0, 200)
nombre5 = randint(0, 200)
nombre6 = randint(0, 200)

nombre_final = randint(1, 1000)

état_initial = (nombre1, nombre2, nombre3, nombre4, nombre5, nombre6)

etat_final = nombre_final

etat = (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)


def gagner(etat):
    return etat == etat_final
```

Problem here is that my `etat` is a `tuple` and `etat_final` is just a number, so it's a problem and I am searching a solution to resolve it.

Comment: "Problem here is that my etat is a tuple and "etat_final" is just a number," right this is indeed a problem. Please focus in your question on _what_ are you trying to achieve and not _how_ you're trying to do so. Currently it's not clear to me at all what you're trying to do other than trying to compare a number to a tuple.

Comment: Given `etat` and a set of operations, there are a large number of possible expressions you could construct (each one could be represented as a tuple-encoded S-expression, for example `('+', ('*', etat[0], etat[1]), ('+', etat[2], etat[3]), ...)` corresponding to `etat[0]*etat[1] + (etat[2] + etat[3]) + ...` The job of `gagner` would be to implement a search of all such tuples, and return those that evaluate to `etat_final`. A naive approach would be generate *all* of them and filter those that don't evaluate to the goal value.

Comment: ok sorry, I try so search a solution  to transform my tuple in a number

Comment: Yes chepner, that's what I did, can I show you ?

Comment: please provide some meaninful context of what you are trying to do, and what output you exptect code to do